# Почему страница опускается на пару пикселей при перезагрузке?

Tags: веб-программирование

Есть обычная web-страница. При перезагрузке каждый раз опускается на 1-2 пикселя вниз. Был подозрения на кодировку, но она ту не при чем. В чем может быть проблема?

Код если будет нужен - кину. Просто мне кажется, что он не нужен.

Comment: То есть если её перезагрузить тысячу раз, то она уедет под нижний край экрана?)

Comment: @andreymal, да, абсолютно верно

Comment: "Код если будет нужен - кину." -- нужен...... "мне кажется, что он не нужен." --- нужен

Comment: @АлексейШиманский что именно? вся верстка?

Comment: Удаляйте из вёрстки различные ненужные части поочерёдно по одной. Когда вдруг перестанет опускаться - значит проблема в последней удалённой части, на неё и стоит обратить всё своё внимание

Comment: Или наоборот, начните делать вёрстку заново и добавляйте части по одной, когда начнёт опускаться — значит проблема в последней добавленной части. Если вдруг начало опускаться с самого начала, значит проблема не в вёрстке, а в вашем браузере

Comment: @andreymal, она появилась с тегом <body>...

Comment: Попробуйте другой браузер, другой компьютер, отключите расширения

Answer (score 0):

проблема в css-свойстве `line-height`. Если оно `<= 1`, то страница будет опускаться. Если `> 1`, то страница будет подниматься.

Comment: Что-то у вас очень сильно сломано... Все сайты используют самые разные line-height (в том числе Stack Overflow) и ни у кого ничего не опускается